# how to navigate to another page by clicking on :before content?

Tags: css, sass, pseudo-element

I am trying to navigate to another page by clicking on :before content of this card, but it is not working

**jsx:**

```
<div className="inner-container-one">
   <Link to="/programDetails">
       <img src={psycho} alt="" />
   </Link>
</div>
```

**scss:**

```
.inner-container-one {
    position: relative;

    &:before {
      content: "weight training ➔";
      vertical-align: middle;
      position: absolute;
      background: orange;
      z-index: 999;
      cursor: pointer;
   }
}
```

**output:**
[image]

Is there any way out so that I can be able to navigate to another page by clicking on :before pseudo-element?

Comment: You cannot add an event handler onto a ::before pseudo element. What you should do is to create a span or even div - add the content into it and position it absolutely to be where you want it. Also - from an accessibility point of view - trying to add a navigational action onto a ::Before pseudo element is wrong- IMO

Comment: Maybe `inner-container-one` is outside Link check it

Comment: And by the way, pseudo elements must only be used for **decorative purposes**, if you have meaningful content, don't use a pseudo element...